# How to use typeahead by API calling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, typeahead.js, typeahead

Here I want to create text box, which can show a matching list of customers after 3 input letters.
I have used **twitter** typeahead with **remote** plugin.
Whenever I enter 3 letters, it started showing a blank box but it doesn't contain any kind of list.
Do I miss anything? Please help me out !!
My markup and jQuery are as below...

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Customer</label>
        <input id="customer" type="text" value="" class="typeahead form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Movies</label>
        <input type="text" value="" class="form-control" />
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>


<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var viewmodel = {};
            var customers = new Bloodhound({
                datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
                queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
                remote: {
                    url: '/api/customers?query=%QUERY',
                    wildcard: '%QUERY'
                }
            });

            $('#customer').typeahead({
                minLength: 3,
                highlight: true
            }, {
                name: 'customers',
                display: 'name',
                source: customers
            }).on("typeahead:select", function (e, customer) {
                viewmodel.customerId = customer.id;
            });
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter typeahead hasn't been updated for more than five years and its broken with new Bootstrap (4/5) and JQuery library. I suggest you to use [JQuery Typeahead](https://github.com/running-coder/jquery-typeahead) which is more recent and features complete. Here is a working example:

```js
$.typeahead({
    input: '.js-typeahead-country_v1',
    order: "desc",
    source: {
        data: [
            "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Andorra", "Angola", "Antigua and Barbuda",
            "Argentina", "Armenia", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh",
            "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bermuda", "Bhutan", "Bolivia",
            "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Botswana", "Brazil", "Brunei", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burma",
            "Burundi", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Cape Verde", "Central African Republic", "Chad",
            "Chile", "China", "Colombia", "Comoros", "Congo, Democratic Republic", "Congo, Republic of the",
            "Costa Rica", "Cote d'Ivoire", "Croatia", "Cuba", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Djibouti",
            "Dominica", "Dominican Republic", "East Timor", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador",
            "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea", "Estonia", "Ethiopia", "Fiji", "Finland", "France", "Gabon",
            "Gambia", "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Greece", "Greenland", "Grenada", "Guatemala", "Guinea",
            "Guinea-Bissau", "Guyana", "Haiti", "Honduras", "Hong Kong", "Hungary", "Iceland", "India",
            "Indonesia", "Iran", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica", "Japan", "Jordan",
            "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kiribati", "Korea, North", "Korea, South", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyzstan", "Laos",
            "Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libya", "Liechtenstein", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg",
            "Macedonia", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta", "Marshall Islands",
            "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mexico", "Micronesia", "Moldova", "Mongolia", "Morocco", "Monaco",
            "Mozambique", "Namibia", "Nauru", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "New Zealand", "Nicaragua", "Niger",
            "Nigeria", "Norway", "Oman", "Pakistan", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", "Paraguay", "Peru",
            "Philippines", "Poland", "Portugal", "Qatar", "Romania", "Russia", "Rwanda", "Samoa", "San Marino",
            "Sao Tome", "Saudi Arabia", "Senegal", "Serbia and Montenegro", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone",
            "Singapore", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Solomon Islands", "Somalia", "South Africa", "Spain",
            "Sri Lanka", "Sudan", "Suriname", "Swaziland", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Syria", "Taiwan",
            "Tajikistan", "Tanzania", "Thailand", "Togo", "Tonga", "Trinidad and Tobago", "Tunisia", "Turkey",
            "Turkmenistan", "Uganda", "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom", "United States",
            "Uruguay", "Uzbekistan", "Vanuatu", "Venezuela", "Vietnam", "Yemen", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"
        ]
    },
    callback: {
        onInit: function (node) {
            console.log('Typeahead Initiated on ' + node.selector);
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-typeahead/2.11.0/jquery.typeahead.min.css">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-typeahead/2.11.0/jquery.typeahead.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<form id="form-country_v1" name="form-country_v1">
    <div class="typeahead__container">
        <div class="typeahead__field">
            <div class="typeahead__query">
                <input class="js-typeahead-country_v1" name="country_v1[query]" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
            <div class="typeahead__button">
                <button type="submit">
                    <i class="typeahead__search-icon"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Of course you can get data from an Ajax API call using the source option from the plugin.